# Shell script - get whole file name

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins

Hi i am a bit confused with one problem, now i have this script in my Jenkins

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic $key" 
-F file=@"case/target/$POM_ARTIFACTID-$POM_VERSION.zip" -X POST $CLOUDHUB_DEPLOY_URL`

It takes the Artifact id and Version from the POM.xml So in that case it is 
"test-1.0.0".zip . This is based on POM,normal name of the file is "test-7c605e12ee7d9424d3a67a656a73bb14c6c92d78.zip" but i want to just let the $POM_ARTIFACTID with the - and read the rest of the string(7c605e12ee7d9424d3a67a656a73bb14c6c92d78) and append it to the file name. I tried to do some regex as -F file=@"case/target/$POM_ARTIFACTID-/*.zip" but unfortunately it did not help. I am very new to the shell scripting so sory if it sound ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my understanding is that you have a file on disk like this:

```
% ls case/target/test-7c605e12ee7d9424d3a67a656a73bb14c6c92d78.zip
case/target/test-7c605e12ee7d9424d3a67a656a73bb14c6c92d78.zip
```

you're right that globbing doesn't work with curl's form upload:

```
% curl -F file=@"case/target/test-*.zip" -X POST localhost:80
curl: (26) couldn't open file "case/target/test-*.zip"
```

but you can use shell globbing to get your file first:

```
% file="$(ls case/target/test-*.zip)"
% echo $file
case/target/test-7c605e12ee7d9424d3a67a656a73bb14c6c92d78.zip
```

and then it works:

```
% curl -F file=@"${file}" -X POST localhost:80
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

your commands might look like:

```
file="$(ls case/target/$POM_ARTIFACTID-*.zip)"
curl -H "Authorization: Basic $key" -F file=@"${file}" -X POST $CLOUDHUB_DEPLOY_URL
```